# Why does this batch file keep freezing?

Tags: batch-file

I am currently making a game in batch. In the following code, sometime after the 10th loop, the batch file stop working completely.

It would be very useful if somebody could help me out.

```
                :: Check for death ::
                if !b0y! equ 0 if !px! equ 0 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 1 if !px! equ 1 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 2 if !px! equ 2 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 3 if !px! equ 3 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 4 if !px! equ 4 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 5 if !px! equ 5 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 6 if !px! equ 6 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 7 if !px! equ 7 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 8 if !px! equ 8 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
                if !b0y! equ 9 if !px! equ 9 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
        ::Checking for player input ::
:getinput
        for /f "delims=" %%x in (control.txt) do set direction=%%x
        set "dir=%direction%"
:checkinput
        if !dir! equ 0 set /a "px=!px!-1" >nul
        if !dir! equ 1 set /a "px=!px!+1" >nul
        if !dir! equ 2 goto pause
        if !dir! equ 3 goto end
        if !dir! equ 4 goto chooseboulder

        echo 4>>control.txt

        :: Choosing Boulder placement ::
:chooseboulder
        set /a "num=%random%*10/32768"
        if !num! equ 0 if !b0y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 1 if !b1y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 2 if !b2y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 3 if !b3y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 4 if !b4y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 5 if !b5y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 6 if !b6y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 7 if !b7y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 8 if !b8y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 9 if !b9y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
        set "b!num!y=9"

    :: Delaying the game 0.75 seconds to make it easier to play ::
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
)
goto loop
```

If You need the full code, please just comment saying so. (I'm kind of reluctant to put all my code just out on the internet for everyone to see.)

Comment: Time for some "printf debugging"...  (`echo useful status message` all over the place to work out where it's stopping)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler OK, I'll guess I'll do that then.

Comment: we don't need your complete code, but a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows us your problem. Some random snippet doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be absurdly obsessed by delayedexpansion.

```
if %b0y% equ %px%timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
```

would appear to substitute for the block of

```
if !b0y! equ 0 if !px! equ 0 timeout /t 1 >nul && goto end
```

none of the `!` is required in the block dealing with `dir`

```
if !dir! equ 0 set /a "px=!px!-1" >nul
```

you could be replace throughout that block with `%` - the quotes are not needed and the `>nul` does nothing

Th entire block of

```
if !num! equ 0 if !b0y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
```

could be replaced by

```
if !b%num%y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder
```

In this case, the value of `num` is substituted for `%num%` and then the value of `b?y` is evaluated - which is the meaning of `!b?y!` - the evaluation of `!var!` is delayed.

It's regarded as bad practice to use command-names as variables or labels (`dir` is a command-name, as is `pause`)

The command

```
echo 4>>control.txt
```

attempts to redirect the output of standard device number 4 (undefined) to the file having executed `echo` which would probably generate `ech is off` to the screen. a digit directly before a redirector will invoke this behaviour for any standard device (0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr, 3-9=undefined) and can be avoided by using

```
>>control.txt echo 4
```

Having said all of that, I now notice an orphan `)` which implies that this is all within one code block (a parenthesised series of statements) invalidating part of what I said about delayedexpansion.

How do you expect us to debug the code when you haven't even shown us **ONE** complete statement?

You also haven't told us what is contained in your file `control.txt` so we can't tell what is being read and have to guess...

And since this is all part of a code block, you should realise that labels are not permitted within a code block, and whereas in the portion of code you've provided, `getinput`, `checkinput` and `chooseboulder` are labels, the very reasn `::` works as a comment is that it's actually an unreachable label. It's ignored by `cmd` because it is a label hence it's useful for comments but it's still a label and will break a code block. Use `rem` for comments within a code block.